# AWS RDS SQL SERVER : admin rights issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I just don't understand that why AWS RDS SQL SERVER does not allow any admin level rights to perform. It simply says I do not have permission. I logged in using master username and password.

```
EXEC sp_addmessage @msgnum = 60000, @severity = 16, 
       @msgtext = N'The item named %s already exists in %s.', 
       @lang = 'us_english';

GRANT CONTROL SERVER TO [adminUser];
```

I am finding pretty hard to figure out , how to deal with this.
   This is forcing me to not to use AWS nemore.

Answer (score 3):

RDS is a managed service provided by AWS. The whole point of RDS is that they manage the server for you. In order to ensure they are able to properly manage it, you do not have full admin rights to the server. They give you enough control that they think you require.

If you need more control, or you feel these restrictions are too limiting, then RDS may not be the service for you.

Answer (score 1):

This is for anyone still looking for the solution, probably RDS parameter group will help you. you can update some of these configurations from AWS console with the RDS parameter group. See this article:

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5329/setting-sql-server-configuration-options-with-aws-rds-parameter-groups/